# IE 8 special character rendering issue

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

I am having a weird issue with IE 8 and special characters.

Basically IE8 is rendering the characters off-centre. I tried to play with language packs etc in IE8 but I cannot work it out.

The html being rendered is fairly simple .e.g

```
<span style="cursor: pointer; ">Avslå registrering</span>
```

You will notice the special a characters circle is off-centre. This only seems to be impacted in IE8, all other IE versions are fine, chrome and firefox are also fine.

E.g. of IE 7/chrome rendering

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7j9e3.jpg

e.g. of IE8 rendering (notice off centre)

http://imgur.com/O3SH9

NOTE: This is not just impacting the span tag. Every piece of element that has the same text is also impacted.